# WSO2 ESB Store array of results in a property

Tags: xml, xpath, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Basically I am getting an array of results from a data service call and I need to pass this array into java.  I am trying to store the array of results in a property mediator somehow, and then pass this into java.

Here is an example of the data service results:

```
<testResponse>
   <result>
      <PARAM1>0</PARAM1>
      <PARAM2>20</PARAM2>
      <PARAM3>40</PARAM3>
   </result>
</testResponse>
```

And here is an example of my java function that I am calling:

```
public static String testFunction(int[] array);
```

And here is a payload for this java function:

```
<payloadFactory>
        <format>
            <p:testFunction xmlns:p="http://test.com">
                <xs:array xmlns:xs="http://test.com">$1</xs:array>
           </p:testFunction>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="$ctx:PROPERTYARRAY"/>
        </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

I am confused about how to set "PROPERTYARRAY".

Right now I am doing something like:

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="PROPERTYARRAY" expression="//testResponse/result/" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

And the log for this is "02040".

How can I get this in array format and send to my java function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this;

```
 <property name="propertyarray" expression="$body"/>
```